# Integrating a $k$-dimensional (multivariate) Gaussian over a convex $k$-polytope

Tags: probability-theory, differential-geometry

**What is the integral of a $k$-dimensional (multivariate) Gaussian over a convex $k$-polytope?**

Here I am specifically interested in $k\in\{2,3\}$, but insight on the general problem would also be appreciated.  I am guessing that there is no closed form in the general case, but what if we restrict the number of vertices of the polytope to at most $k+1$?  If no closed form exists even under this constraint, are there efficient ways to approximate the integral?

Comment: Could you please clarify what do you mean by k-dimensional Gaussian. If it is random $k\times 1$ vector with multivariate normal distribution, I do not see how can you define the integral.

Comment: By "$k$-dimensional Gaussian" I mean: "A distribution in $k$-dimensional Euclidean space that is composed of univariate normal distributions in each dimension."

Comment: The base case, when $k=1$, is simple: It is just asking to find the area under a univariate normal distribution in some subset of $\mathbb{R}$.  When $k=2$, the problem I am trying to solve is finding the volume under the distribution in the region defined by a convex polygon in $\mathbb{R}^2$.  When $k=3$, the problem boils down to integrating the distribution over some convex polyhedron in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: so in other words, you are looking to compute the volume of the polytope, but with respect to the Gaussian measure?

Comment: @Slowsolver: exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you want to compute the following integral:

\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{(2\pi|\Sigma|)^{n/2}}\int_{V_k}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}(x-a)^T\Sigma^{-1}(x-a)\right)dx
\end{align*}

where $V_k\subset \mathbb{R}^k$ is a $k$-polytope, $a\in \mathbb{R}^k$ is the mean and $\Sigma$ is the $k\times k$ covariance matrix of $k$-variate normal vector.

My approach would be doing a change of variables $y=\Sigma^{1/2}(x-a)$ and then integrate by one variable at a time, since the integrand function will be a product of one-variable functions. If $\Sigma^{1/2}V_k$ is a $k$-cube then the integration is straightforward. For the general case it will not be easy. Take $k=2$, normal with zero mean and unit covariance matrix, and $V_2$ a triangle with vertices in $(0,0)$, $(1,0)$, $(0,1)$. Then your integral will be
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{V_2}e^{-\frac{x_1^2}{2}}e^{-\frac{x_2^2}{2}}dx_1dx_2&=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{1}e^{-\frac{x_1^2}{2}}dx_1\int_{0}^{1-x_1}e^{-\frac{x_2^2}{2}}dx_2\\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_0^1e^{-\frac{x_1^2}{2}}(\Phi(1-x_1)-\Phi(0))dx_1
\end{align}
which I do not think has closed formula. (I might be wrong).

As for approximation, I do not see why standard numerical integral solving methods would not work.

Comment: Thanks!  I was basically throwing this question out there in the hopes that there are some relaxations that make it closed form.  By "approximation" I really meant something like bounding the polytope by a $k$-cube convex hull and using its integration as an upper bound on the polytope's integration.

Comment: Rough idea: With this change of variables there's a zero mean zero correlation gaussian. Expand facets to hyperplanes, each defines two halfspaces. All hyperplanes make a partition of the space, bounded polytope in the middle and some exterior regions. Each integral over a halfspace reduces to a 1D error function(I think) and is the sum of the integrals over some of the regions, and there are $2M$ such integrals and a sum-to-1 constraint. So $2M+1$ equations, not sure about the number of exterior regions;can this linear system be solved for the integral over each region including the polytope?